# Getting 'Non-constant expression as array bound' when field is const

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to define a multidimensional array using my constant field as its dimension, but I'm getting a compilation error saying that the expression is not constant. Is there any other way to do this so I can use a constant field defined in constructor initialization list as an array dimension?

Translation for English-speaking majority:

```
class FunctionWave2D : public DisallowedDomainPoints
{
protected:
    double th; 
    double l; a
    double d, dd; 
    const int number_sqrt;  //here's the constant

    double **second_derivatives;

protected:
    bool elasticTenstionOnly;

public:
    FunctionWave2D(int number, double elasticModulus, double dampingFactor, double oscillationDampingFactor, double length)
        :DisallowedDomainPoints(number * LAYER_COUNT),
        th(elasticModulus), d(dampingFactor), dd(oscillationDampingFactor),
        elasticTensionOnly(false),
        l(length/(sqrt(number)-1)),
        number_sqrt(sqrt(number))
    {   
        second_derivatives = new double[number_sqrt][number_sqrt][LAYER_COUNT];
//(...)
```

Comment: @AJMansfield it maybe local language as opposed to being obfuscated

Comment: (I think it's polish)

Comment: @AJMansfield Variables are reasonable, it's Polish. They are very long though

Comment: @ShamimHafiz I guess you might be right.  The names are still bad though.

Comment: Ok, people, I've edited my comment.

Comment: Is it possible that you have another constructor that you aren't showing and that constructor doesn't initialize ilosc_sqrt and that constructor is invoked?

Comment: Yes, it's polish - sorry for the long variable names - it's not my code, it's just a framework in which I have to make changes to implement the right version of physical equations. Believe me, I am struggling with those names as well.
There is no other constructor.

Comment: what is `ILOSC_WARSTW` ?

Comment: it's a preprocessor defined constant:
    #define ILOSC_WARSTW 3

Comment: I've added a translation of it, its the best I can do with just google translate, since I don't actually know the language.

Comment: const != constant *expression*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array bound has to be a compile-time constant. A non-static const data member is not a compile-time constant; it gets its value at runtime, when the object is constructed.

So, basically, if you need to set the size of that array at runtime you'll have to build up all the pieces with `operator new[]`. Essentially,

```
int **data_2d = new int*[runtime_size];
for (int i = 0; i < runtime_size; ++i)
    data_2d[i] = new int[runtime_size];
```

The extension to a 3d-array is straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, the term "constant expression" specifically refers to an expression whose value is known at compile-time.  It's not the same as a `const` variable.  For example, `137` is a constant expression, but in this code:

```
int function(int x) {
    const int k = x;
}
```

The value of `k` is not a constant expression, since its value can't be determined at compile-time.

In your case, you have a data member declared as

```
 const int ilosc_sqrt;  //here's the constant
```

Even though this is marked `const`, its value is not known at compile-time.  It is initialized in the initializer list as

```
ilosc_sqrt(sqrt(ilosc))
```

This value can't be determined until the program is actually run, hence the error.  (Note that the new C++11 `constexpr` keyword is designed, among other things, to make constant expressions a lot easier to identify in source code and to make it possible to do more advance compile-time computations with constants.)

To fix this, you will either need to split up your initialization into smaller steps:

```
drugie_pochodne = new double**[ilosc_sqrt];
for (int i = 0; i < ilosc_sqrt; i++) {
    drugie_pochodne[i] = new double*[ilosc_sqrt];
    for (int j = 0; j < ilosc_sqrt; j++) {
        drugie_pochodne[j] = new double[ILOSC_WARSTW];
    }
}
```

Or use a library like Boost.MultiArray, which supports a cleaner initialization syntax.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that, you saved me a lot of pointless debugging.